# Details about "Number of Input pdf" or "Input PDF Character Len"

Tags: pdf, pdftk

I'm using pdftk within my application to generate a composite pdf of several individual pdf files. When, for whatever reason, pdftk does run.
If feel that the reason is the amount of Input files e.g. 586 or the Character Length of Input pdf files - in my case 35624.
What are the limits for Input files in pdftk?
Thank you for answer